# SQL query running current value by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that returns the last non-null value next to all subsequent dates until a new non-null value is encountered.The input table would look something like this:

```
DATE           VALUE
==========     ======
01/01/2015     1
02/01/2015     NULL
03/01/2015     NULL
04/01/2015     2
05/01/2015     NULL
```

And I would like the resulting query table would look like this:

```
DATE           CURRENT VALUE
==========     =============
01/01/2015     1
02/01/2015     1
03/01/2015     1
04/01/2015     2
05/01/2015     2
```

I've have tried searching around for an answer but I haven't come up with anything. Forgive me if this kind of question is common. Thanks

Comment: Are the gaps / missing days in your data? If that's the case, then you'll probably want to pre-build a table of dates and use that for outer apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is using `outer apply`:

```
select t.date, coalesce(t.value, t2.value) as current_value
from table t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.value
      from table t2
      where t2.value is not null and
            t2.date <= t.date
      order by t2.date desc
     ) tt;
```

If you know that the values are increasing, then in SQL Server 2012+ you can use `max()`:

```
select date, max(value) over (order by date) as current_value
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Another way*, if the date field is `unique`, and is `increasing by one` `with no gap` then you can  use a `recursive cte`:

```
with cte (dt,value) as
(
 select top 1 date , value from tbl where value is not null
 union all
 select t.date, isnull(t.value,cte.value)
 from tbl t 
 join cte on t.date=dateadd(month,1,cte.dt)
)
select * from cte
```

[the FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad0e4/5)

Answer (score 1):

If the Null Rows in the Data were at most one row at a time, you could use [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) in a `COALESCE` to repeat the previous row's value:

```
SELECT t1.Date, COALESCE(t1.Value, LAG (Value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.Date ASC))
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER By T1.Date ASC;
```

Unfortunately of course, your data has gaps of two or more rows, which would mean you would need to continue to extend the `COALESCING`, which leads to something quite horrid:

```
SELECT t1.Date, 
       COALESCE(t1.Value, 
                LAG (Value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.Date ASC), 
                LAG (Value, 2) OVER (ORDER BY t1.Date ASC),
                ...)
FROM Table1 t1
ORDER By T1.Date ASC
```

Which isn't generic at all.